# Hash for duplicates images doesn't work for all duplicates

Tags: java, hash, phash

I need to detect duplicates of images. This is what I did:

```java
try {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte fileData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fi.read(fileData);
    fi.close();
    return new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest(fileData)).toString(16);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("cannot read file " + file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
}
```

The reason it doesn't work for all images is because of course files need to be exactly the same. For instance, it's practically the same, but has a different size (195 KB against 196 KB):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzXq9.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRY2r.jpg

What bothers me, however, is the fact that I got two different hashes for an image that has exactly same size, same colour profile, same resolution, etc. (I'm not sure if I can post the image since  it's a person's face and I haven't asked for their consent.)

Comment: *What bothers me, however...* Why does that bother you? You just acknowledged that the files must be **exactly** the same, and clearly two images that have the *...same size, same colour profile, same resolution, etc...* may still have other differences.

Comment: BTW the images you posted are useless for this question, as you yourself wrote "has a different size". If you are not allowed to post  the relevant images, try some (other) tool that calculates checksums  (or add the files to a 7-Zip file - it does show the corresponding CRC) so you can see if the **content** is the same - Unix system usually have such tools, or Windows File Explorer if opening a ZIP file

Comment: jpeg images use lossy compression. If different settings are used to compress the image, e.g. different quality settings, then the result will likely be different. They may look the same to the human eye, but if you uncompressed them to pixel arrays, there may be differences. Do you want to obtain a hash which is the same for all uncompressed pixel arrays? In that case, you may need to uncompress it, then hash the pixel array. If two compressions are compressed slightly differently however, you'll still get different hashes.

Comment: A hash is unique by definition for the exact input given. Even 1 bit difference should give a new hash. If it was not the case, your hash algorithm would be broken. Hashing is useful for many reasons, among others to determine if a file is unchanged or not. It is not useful for comparing if images are visually the same. 
Another approach: if your file is different because of a known reason (like different metadata), you could try to get the data parts of the file you know are supposed to be the same and compare the hashes over that data.

Comment: So what would you suggest to find identical images (visually) but that have only a different info (like different size)?

Comment: @user85421 CRC is indeed different. However I am not sure what is different.

Comment: `fi.read(fileData);` ← You really, really should not ignore [the value returned](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) by that call.  But the better way is `DigestInputStream d = new DigestInputStream(fi, messageDigest); d.transferTo(OutputStream.nullOutputStream()); byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();`, which will compute a digest without trying to store the entire file contents in memory.

Comment: `FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte fileData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
   fi.read(fileData);
   DigestInputStream d = new DigestInputStream(fi, messageDigest); 
   d.transferTo(OutputStream.nullOutputStream()); 
   byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(fileData);
   fi.close();
   return new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16); `

@VGR, correct?

Comment: Remove the declaration of `fileData` and remove the call to `fi.read`.  And remember to close the DigestOutputStream (which will automatically close `fi`).

Comment: I am still asking since I am not sure sure if the argument of digest has to be empty or not since in code you provided was empty. 
Updated code:
`FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
   DigestInputStream d = new DigestInputStream(fi, messageDigest); 
   d.transferTo(OutputStream.nullOutputStream()); 
   byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(new byte[(int) file.length()]);
   d.close();
   return new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);`